# Word - convert list of images to images

Tags: vba, ms-word

I don't work much in Word VBA so I approached this similar to how I'd approach it in excel, which may not have been optimal. I also didn't *see* any places for errors to be handled.

This takes a Word document that has a list of URLs (pointing to .jpg), takes the URLs, places them as images on another sheet and then scales them to as large as they can get on an 8.5x11 while maintaining aspect ratio.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub URLToImage()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sourceDocument As Document
    Set sourceDocument = ThisDocument
    Dim imageURLs() As String
    imageURLs = GetURLArray(sourceDocument)
    Dim targetDocument As Document
    Set targetDocument = Documents.Add
    PrintImages imageURLs, targetDocument
    ResizeImages targetDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetURLArray(ByVal sourceDocument As Document) As String()
    Dim imageURLs() As String
    ReDim imageURLs(1 To 2)
    Dim imageURL As String
    Dim beginCharacter As Long
    Dim endCharacter As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    For i = LBound(imageURLs) To sourceDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        imageURL = sourceDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
        beginCharacter = InStr(1, imageURL, "http", vbTextCompare)
        endCharacter = InStr(1, imageURL, "jpg")
        If beginCharacter > 0 And endCharacter > 0 Then
            imageURL = Mid(imageURL, beginCharacter, endCharacter + 3 - beginCharacter)
            ReDim Preserve imageURLs(1 To j)
            imageURLs(j) = imageURL
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    GetURLArray = imageURLs
End Function

Private Sub PrintImages(ByRef imageURLs() As String, ByVal targetDocument As Document)
    Dim imageURL As String
    Dim i As Long
    With targetDocument
        For i = LBound(imageURLs) To UBound(imageURLs)
            imageURL = imageURLs(i)
            With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
                .Name = imageURL
                .Execute
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeImages(ByVal targetDocument As Document)
    '72 points per inch
    Const EIGHT_AND_HALF_INCHES As Long = 72 * 8 + 72 / 2
    Const NO_MARGIN As Long = 0
    Dim i As Long
    With targetDocument
        .PageSetup.LeftMargin = NO_MARGIN
        .PageSetup.RightMargin = NO_MARGIN
        .PageSetup.TopMargin = NO_MARGIN
        .PageSetup.BottomMargin = NO_MARGIN
        For i = .InlineShapes.Count To 2 Step -1
            '.InlineShapes(i).Range.InsertBreak Type:=7
            .InlineShapes(i).Width = EIGHT_AND_HALF_INCHES
        Next
        .InlineShapes(1).Width = EIGHT_AND_HALF_INCHES
    End With
End Sub
```